# no data loaded in dynamic input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I am using some [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) for file upload. This works well for any file `input` except when I hide this `input` in some popup that shows up when some event is triggered. 
Then, the file `input` appears in the popup, but when I load some file, no event is detected, namely

```
$(document).on("input#file-upload","change",function(){
     console.log("file is loaded");
});
```

triggers nothing
even if in my console I see that my `input` file has a correct new value.

Comment: So do you have multiple `input` fields with the same `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead. First ***event*** then ***selector*** for [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on("change", "input#file-upload", function(){
    console.log("file is loaded");
});
```